# Unity 2D Game Passing Score to Next Scene and Level Restart

Tags: c#, scene

I'm trying to make a 2D platformer game and I am having a problem with trying to pass score to next scene and also if I use onDestroy method I can't reset the score when player dies. How would you go about doing it? This is my script for collecting items:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Collecting_Items : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Text coinsberryText;
    [SerializeField] private int coinsberry;
    
    public Text pointsText;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource collectSoundEffect;


    private void OnEnable() {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Strawberry")) 
        {
            coinsberry = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Strawberry");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Strawberry")) 
        {
            
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            AddScore();
            collectSoundEffect.Play();

        }
    }

    void AddScore() {

        coinsberry++;
        coinsberryText.text = " :" + coinsberry;
        Setup(coinsberry);

    }

    public void OnDestroy() {

        savePrefs();
    }

    void savePrefs() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Strawberry",coinsberry);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }



    public void Setup(int score) 
    {
       
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        pointsText.text = score.ToString() + "  :Strawberry";
        
    }
}
```

This is my code for restart level

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManagerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject gameOverUI;

    public GameObject scoreUI;

    public static GameManagerScript instance;


    public void gameOver() {

        gameOverUI.SetActive(true);
        scoreUI.SetActive(false);

        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();

    }



    public void restart() {
        
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        
    }

    public void mainMenu() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Start Scene 1");
    }

    public void quit() {
        Application.Quit();
        Debug.Log("Quit");
    }


}
```

So I tried on DontDestoryOnLoad but that for some reason ended the next scene out of nowhere so then I went and tried playerprefs it works but not as intended if anyone is willing to help it will be greatly appricated thanks.